# Using Hibernate, Spring Data JPA in multithreading

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

How is hibernate working in a multithreaded environment? Say I have a user table with a unique constraint on email. When I want to create 20 users in a single thread, there is no problem.

However, when I do multithreading, it will get Unique Constraint violation error.

I am doing Spring batch with multithreading, itemreader, processor and writer are Bean singleton.

I am processing records, these records will contain duplicate Emails.

I have a user Repository and a user pojos. When in the processor, I do

```
User user = userRepo.findByEmail(email);
if(user == null) {
//create  user
} else {
//update user
}
user = userRepo.save(user); //I know this didn't commit to db
//tried with saveAndFlush,  also not working, same exception
```

When I do it in multiple thread, it will generate DataIntegretityViolation. So I guess probably because of no synchronized. However, when I add synchronized to this block of code, still I will get DataIntegretityViolation Exception.

My question is how this user object is shared between different thread?

If thread 1 and thread 2 both execute this block, thread 1 aquires lock first, so Thread 2 needs to wait. So in thread 1 it saved a user with email abc. Now thread 2 also tries to create user with email abc.

The expected results should be thread 2 do findByEmail, it should be able to find the user created by thread 1 and doing updates on it. It should not create another user with email abc.

Also somehow when I do a findBySomething in Jpa, it will also cause unique key violation, why will it happen to select?

Need some help. Am I do it in a wrong way? Is there some properties I need to  specifically set? I also set up datasource in application properties.